# Installing from Android Market. Unknown reason-102

Tags: android, google-play

I got this error message when I try to install for testing my app from android market

"Installation error." It's followed by "Unknown reason-102".

Is this my apk or my phone???

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with using a different signing certificate. The Android docs suggest a life of 10,000 days, but that now creates expiry dates *after* the end of time in *nix timestamps, which is some time in **2038**. I generated a new cert that expires in 2037 and resubmitted the apk and it now installs ok. Unfortunately I had to change the identifier of the app and copy all the descriptions/graphics to the "new" app because play won't let you change the cert on an existing app.

I could install my apk directly on my phone but when it came through market/play it would fail, every time. I thought it was getting corrupted during the submission process and google said they could not help me. It looks like a bug the market/play app to me.