# Android InApp Purchases Error Code 102

Tags: android, android-billing

I am implementing anjlab Library for in app purchasing.
I try to purchase item.some time i get error .and error code is 102.
If i again try t0 purchase , Purchasing successful with out showing google purchases dialog.
I am following.

https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

Can some one telling about Error Code 102.
what is this? and what is the reason of this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error Code 102 refers to connection refused.

```
Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): Unknown error
```

Please go through the following link I hope it may help. Link gives the description of network errors but related to Chrome. As your error is a standard error and might not because of your code but due to some configuration settings.
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/117805?hl=en

I need to made some edit if above thing doesn't help much please go through this questions:
[Installing from Android Market. Unknown reason-102](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559039/installing-from-android-market-unknown-reason-102)

Answer (score 3):

Error code 102 means **Invalid signature.**

The error is caused because of the wrong license key.

The solution is to use the proper license key from

> Play console > Your App > Development Tools > Licensing & in-app billing

Comment: Thanks it solved the issue. I think adding test users to license updates license keys as well.